# How to put different user inputs in a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a high school student and I just don't get how to insert multiple user inputs in a paragraph

Comment: Just include more than one `<input>` - what exactly is confusing about that? What does your "paragraph" look like?

Comment: Can you add some more details. The question is unclear

Comment: At first its different kinds of forms and the user will answer them then when you submit it the answer will be inserted in a story

Comment: If i'm understanding correctly,By no of user  inputs,you will create paragraph which will be saved. You can write javascript function to create para from user input e.g. " "+ document.formname.inputname1.value +"2nd input is"+document.formname.inputname2.value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JavaScript, you can take the value of the input field and put it somewhere else on the page.
Example:

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <script>
        function insertTexts() {
            document.getElementById('girlsname').innerHTML = document.getElementById('inputname').value;
            document.getElementById('destination').innerHTML = document.getElementById('inputdest').value;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Once upon a time, a girl called <span id="girlsname">_______</span>,
        made a trip from London to <span id="destination">_______</span>.
    </p>
    <p>
        Enter the girl's name: <input id="inputname"> <br/>
        Enter the destination: <input id="inputdest"> <br/>
        <button onclick="insertTexts();">Insert input into story</button>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```